# Component for covering a very tiny hole (pinhole camera aperture)

Tags: camera, component-selection

I am experimenting with a pinhole camera - it is basically a camera with a very small hole (only 0,2 mm in diameter) instead of a lens ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera))

I am trying to design the shutter - something that I could control to cover/uncover the pinhole (so light passes through only when intended). How would you design such a thing? The following solutions have crossed my mind:

1. Mechanically cover the hole using a lid. I guess a solenoid or linear actuator could be used, but the hole is so small (only 0,2mm!) so it seems a bit overkill?
2. I could put a "smart film" on top of the pinhole - the ones that turn transparent when you put current through them and are opaque otherwise. However, that may not be such a good idea to use in a camera since it might impact the imaging quality...

Do you know of any other solutions? If there is a component that could move a small object just a half millimeter forward/backward (and is also reasonably cheap), that would probably suffer.

Comment: A [TO-5 micro solenoid](http://www.lineelectric.com/solenoids/wssolenoid.html) might be just the right thing for this.

Comment: +1 Nice part! Is it easily available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think a solenoid is overkill? It sounds like a perfect solution. There are very small solenoids on the market. In fact, for such a short travel with low mass, I'd consider winding one by hand.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there solenoids that small. This is why I love stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the very small weight of the shutter, and the small distance it needs to travel, a simple electromagnetic coil actuator/solenoid would work. All you need is a bit of magnet wire wrapped in a coil (use a sewing bobbin) and a small magnet.

[image]

Very popular in micro rc groups, where weight and power are a concern.

[This](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=185270) page has an extensive primer on the idea, building and mounting.